# How to implement instagram similar like effect in ios?

Tags: ios, instagram

I am developing a social app in which I want to implement like functionality similar to instagram, there are feeds with images similar to instagram when user double taps any image then it should show a heart icon with animation similar to instagram. I tried to do the same thing but unable to achieve the animation, can anybody tell me how can I do that.
I am attaching the image of instagram like functionality.
[image]

Comment: You question sounds like a request for code. Instead, show your code and describe what is not working.

Comment: No I am not asking for code, I am just asking an idea that how can I implement

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an implementation:

```
- (void) animateLike {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        heartPopup.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
                heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
                heartPopup.alpha = 0.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

**Code For Swift 3.0**

```
func likeAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {() -> Void in
        heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        heartPopup.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {() -> Void in
            heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {() -> Void in
                heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                heartPopup.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
                heartPopup.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

`heartPopup` is a UIImageView, set it up in the interface builder in the center of the image and set alpha to zero on it. Call the above method to animate the like effect.

#### Swift 4 (code from comment)

```
if let bigLikeImageV = likeImageV, liked == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            bigLikeImageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.6, y: 1.6)
            bigLikeImageV.alpha = 1.0
        }) { finished in
            bigLikeImageV.alpha = 0.0
            bigLikeImageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
}
```

Comment: Alternate version of Instagram-like heartbeat animation using CABasicAnimation & CAAnimationGroup https://gist.github.com/w-i-n-s/2ac5a02237cb32ab93901741e581d24b

Comment: Exact instagram like animation

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.4 initialSpringVelocity:.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            self.imageViewDoubleTapLike.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.6, 1.6);
            self.imageViewDoubleTapLike.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.imageViewDoubleTapLike.alpha = 0.0;
            self.imageViewDoubleTapLike.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        }];

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass (HEARTShapedView) of UIView, which contains the just the heart-shape drawn as a UIBezierPath, added to a CAShapedLayer, and animate it with CABasicAnimation during the `layoutSubviews`. Then, when animation is completed, remove heart shaped view (self) from it's superview.

To use it in your tableview, add it as a subview to your tableview cell, or image view, and the view should animate and remove it self after completion.